# Adobe Creative SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, adobecreativesdk

I'm trying to integrate Adobe Creative SDK with swift and followed the 'getting started' from the Adobe Creative documentation which does not support swift, so i looked for an example to show me how to make the bridging and implementation in swift, cause my trial was unsuccessful and i get a linker error, 
'framework not found AdobeCreativeSDKImage'
but as you can see all the frameworks are in my project...

[image]

i'm looking for an example project to see how it is done or something that will help me understand how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem might be that you're pointing to frameworks that aren't in the project directory.

¿what does your Build Setting for *Framework Search Paths* look like?

mine are like this,
[image: Framework Search Paths]

you have to

- remove the existing entries in the Link Build Phase
- move the frameworks to somewhere within your project folder
- add the frameworks again to the Link Build Phase

Comment: Eventually i found out that what solved the problem for me was changing the 'Debug Information Format' in ' Build Settings' to 'DWARF' & not 'DWARF with dSYM File'.

Comment: that's interesting, i don't believe i had to mess with that.  ¿was it one of those new Xcode version Build Setting Upgrade warnings?

Comment: as much as i can remember... yes

Comment: okay, I think I had to do that too.
out of curiosity, ¿did you just intuitively move the frameworks into your project folder like I suggested?

Comment: I followed the tutorials and documentation of Adobe creative and other sources online, i can't remember if i did intuitively or i found something that directed me to that direction.